# ¿Por qué desde Heroku muestra como fecha un dia antes a la fecha actual?

Tags: nodejs, angular, express, heroku

Tengo mi proyecto hecho con **Angular** y **node/express** subido a **Heroku** con **postgresql** como base de datos a la cual me conecto de forma local con **pgAdmin4**.
Cuando el usuario hace la compra de un producto, se crea la orden de compra y los datos se guardan en mi **tabla orders**.
Me fijo en la tabla y como fecha de la orden de compra figura la de **hoy 31/3/2021**, hasta ahi perfecto!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aca viene lo extraño, en el servidor de **Heroku** cuando muestro los datos de la orden, la fecha figura como **30/3/2021** es decir **un dia antes**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aca **por consola** la fecha la muestra bien desde heroku:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si mi proyecto lo pruebo en mi servidor local la fecha la muestra bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Por qué sucede esto?. No se si es necesario pero por las dudas les muestro como guardo la orden de compra.

**Desde Angular**

Aca en **form-purchase.component.ts** guardo los datos de la **orden de compra en una localStorage**

```js
order = {} as Order;
// fecha local
currentDate = new Date();
  
orderData(){
    if (this.form.valid){
      // el objeto order esta vinculado con un [(ngModel)] en los input
      this.order.order_date = this.currentDate; // aca guardo la fecha actual
      console.log('FECHA: ' + this.order.order_date);
      console.log('ID USER: ' + this.order.id_user);
      console.log('PROVINCIA: ' + this.order.provincia);
      console.log('LOCALIDAD: ' + this.order.localidad);
      console.log('DOMICILIO: ' + this.order.adress);
      console.log('TELEFONO: ' + this.order.phone_number);
      console.log('PRECIO TOTAL: ' + this.order.total_price);
      // guardo en la local storage
      localStorage.setItem('orderData', JSON.stringify(this.order));
    }
  }
```

Aca **successful-purchase.componente.ts** donde **recibo la localstorage con los datos de la orden** para ser guardados en la base de datos:

```js
constructor(
    public orderService: OrderService,
  ) {

      // obtengo los datos de la orden de la localStorage 'orderData' creada en form-purchase.component.ts
      this.order = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('orderData'));
      
      // creo la orden de compra
      this.createOrder();   
    }

  createOrder() {
    // se crea la orden de compra
    this.orderService.createOrder(this.order).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log('La orden fue creada exitosamente');
        // se crea el detalle de la orden de compra
        this.createOrderDetail();
      },
      (err) => console.error('No se pudo crear la orden ' + err.error.message)
    );
  }
```

servicio **orderService.ts**

```js
SERVER = 'http://localhost:3000';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    if (!isDevMode()) {
      this.SERVER = 'https://bookstore-cds-server.herokuapp.com';
    }
  }

  createOrder(order: Order) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.SERVER}/orders/create`, order);
  }
```

Comment: yo creo que puede ser por el timezone, checa en tu petición en la fecha que tz trae

Comment: Gracias por responder...me fije por consola como trae la fecha mi peticion y efectivamente muestra la de hoy: FECHAS DE ORDEN: 2021-03-31T00:00:00.000Z Ahi subo una imagen de lo que sale por consola en mi publicacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCIONADO, siguiendo este tutorial: [cambiar timezone en Heroku app](https://dev.to/paulasantamaria/change-the-timezone-on-a-heroku-app-2b4)

1. **Login** en la **pagina de Heroku**.
2. voy a mi **app**.
3. Click en **Settings**.
4. click en boton **Reveal Config Vars**.
5. Agrego una key **TZ** y como value **America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires**
   y click en boton **Add**.

[image: Cambiar el timezone en Heroku app]